# Converting gene symbols between species

Tags: gene, sequence-homology

I have a list of genes in a mouse model

How I can find the equivalent gene symbol/name for human from them?

This is my list

```
CD45
MHC II
CD11b
Ly6C
Ly6G
F4/80
CD11c
CD38
Arg1
SiglecF
CD206
CD62L
CD103
iNOS
PD-L1
TNFa
CD64
TCRgd
Foxp3
RORgt
CD8α
Tbet
CD25
IFN-γ
CD44
CD86
CD80
PD-1
B220
NK1.1
CD19
CD4
TCR β
```

From these I only find two homologous

[image: enter link description here]

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way is [BioMart](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview). Help video to get you started [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvGT2G0-hYA). Use the mouse genes dataset and filter by the list of gene names, get the mouse gene name and the human gene name (listed under homologues) as attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much I checked and likely from 33 genes, two genes have corresponding please look at the screen shot in my main post? How I find what is the conventional (standard names of these genes please?

Comment: There is no "conventional name", you're going to have to be more specific. The table has both EnsEMBL Gene Identifiers and HGNC Gene Symbols. That should suffice for any analysis.

Comment: That's just the first ten lines of your output, use the _View_ _All_ or downloads to get the full table, as was stated in the help video I sent you. You may also wish to untick some of the default options, as you're getting a line in your table for every transcript, which you don't need.