# Getting conventional gene symbol for Seurat

Tags: scrnaseq, gene, seurat, 10x-genomics

I have a Seurat object made by human single cells

I am mapping some genes on that but no sign of expression

When I GOOGLE for those genes I see the genes have different names

How I know Seurat uses which gene name please

This is my list

```
CD45
MHC II
CD11b
Ly6C
Ly6G
F4/80
CD11c
CD38
Arg1
SiglecF
CD206
CD62L
CD103
iNOS
PD-L1
TNFa
CD64
TCRgd
Foxp3
RORgt
CD8α
Tbet
CD25
IFN-γ
CD44
CD86
CD80
PD-1
B220
NK1.1
CD19
CD4
TCR β
```

From this list only 6 genes being mapped on the Seurat data

Comment: You have [already asked this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/16159/converting-gene-symbols-between-species) and it has been answered - with the exact same response. Why are you opening multiple threads instead of exploring more on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use Biomart to figure out the official names for those genes based on their aliases.

Comment: Can I trust NCBI? For instance this link which says TBX21 is an official gene name? https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/30009

Comment: Yes, you can trust NCBI. Like I said in an earlier comment, HGNC provides the "official" gene symbols, and NCBI/EnsEMBL cross-referencing is reliable.